# Lord Shiva wearing Rudraksha

Tags: shiva, reference-request, rudraksha, rudra

[image: OM Namah Shivay]

How many Rudraksha Lord Pashupati is wearing over the Wrists (lower and higher near the shoulders) and is there any reference over the Scriptures about it?

Comment: We can answer regarding how many Rudrakshas are recommended to be worn on the various parts of the body for a Shiva bhakta. But I don't think we can answer the same about Lord Shiva himself.

Answer (score 1):

As per the **[Devi Bhagwat Puran](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57381.html)** discussion on the glories of the RUdraksh, the following is mentioned:

> He who holds thirty-two Rudrākṣa beads on his neck, forty on his head, six on each ear (12 on two ears), **twenty four beads on two hands (twelve on each hand) thirty-two beads on two arms (sixteen on each),** one bead on each eye and one bead on the hair on the crown, and one hundred and eight beads on the breast, (251 in all) becomes himself Mahā Deva.

Although this is not mentioned as a direct count of the beads worn by Shiva but the concluding words that someone who wears this number of beads becomes Mahadev himself is quite suggestive.